# Passing Function two level deeper in React

Tags: reactjs

Here's the code

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { commerce } from "./lib/commerce";
import { Products, Navbar } from "./components";

const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
    setProducts(data);
  };

  const fetchCart = async () => {
    setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
  };

  const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
    const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);

    setCart(item.cart);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
    fetchCart();
  }, []);

  console.log(cart);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Products products={products} onAddtoCart={handleAddToCart} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Products.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

import Product from "./Product/Product";
import useStyles from "./styles";

const Products = ({ products, onAddToCart }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

**Product.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardMedia,
  CardContent,
  CardActions,
  Typography,
  IconButton,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { AddShoppingCart } from "@material-ui/icons";

import useStyles from "./styles";

const Product = ({ product, onAddToCart }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={product.media.source}
        title={product.name}
      />
      <CardContent>
        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
          <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
            {product.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5">
            {product.price.formatted_with_symbol}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.description }}
          variant="body2"
          color="textSecondary"
        />
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.CardActions}>
        <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart" onClick={() => onAddToCart(product.id, 1)}>
          <AddShoppingCart />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Here's my problem:
I can't pass the `handleAddToCart` function from **App.js** to **Product.jsx**. I'm passing `handleAddToCart` to **Products.jsx** first, then I'm passing it to **Product.jsx** as `onAddToCart`. But what happens is that I get an error and it says that `onAddToCart` is not a function in **Product.jsx**. Can anyone provide me a solution and tell me the reason why this happens?

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[CONSOLE_ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5GET.png)

Comment: take a look at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-hook-img40

Comment: Is it the exactly same code as is while you were getting the console error? Cause console says that the error is in `handleAddToCart` at line *16* of `Product.jsx` but there is not such a function.

Comment: @Jax-p oh, my bad. I edited the post. Kindly check it again. Thank you.

Comment: @Dave Uhmm sorry but I still see the same error.

Comment: Try to create a function inside Product like `onClickHandler` that calls `onAddToCart`. It is not recommended to create an arrow function when passing props.

Comment: in your Product.jsx try this `<IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart" onClick={onAddToCart(product.id, 1)}>`  instead of `<IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart" onClick={() => onAddToCart(product.id, 1)}>`

Comment: @Jax-p I changed the error again.

Comment: @MihaiMoraru I tried creating a function inside Product. `function onClickHandler(){onAddToCart(product.id, 1)}` then calling it as `onClick={onClickHandler}`, it still shows that `onAddToCart` is not a function

Comment: @Sakshi I tried it, still showing that `onAddToCart ` is not a function

Comment: Perhaps add a `console.log()` inside your `onClick` event handler and print out the value of `onAddToCart`. Is it null or undefined when you do? If so, it's probably worth including a screenshot as part of your q. If it's not null or undefined, what value does `onAddToCart` have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
<div>
  <Navbar />
  <Products products={products} onAddtoCart={handleAddToCart} />
</div>
```

onAdd **t** oCart need to be onAdd **T** oCart

```
<div>
  <Navbar />
  <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @arnaud. I didn't noticed that. I can't believe that a single letter gave me hours of headache. I'll try to be more careful next time. Again, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Please have fun for the rest :-)